# Automapper: Ignore exact match and use postfix match instead

Tags: automapper

I am trying to work out how to populate `Foo` from `FooConfig`:

```
class Bar
{
   int A;
   int B;
}

class Foo
{
   Bar BarValues;
   Bar BarErrorValues;
}

class FooConfig
{
   int A;
   int B;
   int AError;
   int BError;
}
```

`FooConfig` is essentially a flattened version of `Foo`.

I can populate the `BarValues` easily with AutoMapper (by having a map defined for `FooConfig` to `Bar`), but I am having trouble getting the `BarErrorValues` populated - everything I try it ends up with the `A` and `B` values in it instead of the `AError` and `BError` values.

I suspect I need to use a "transformer" or `RecognizePostfixes` (although this does not seem to work as I tried it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. It appears that if AutoMapper finds an exact match then the name transformer is never used. Bugger :( Here is the AutoMapper source code that shows it:

```
private static MemberInfo FindTypeMember(IEnumerable<MemberInfo> modelProperties, IEnumerable<MethodInfo> getMethods, string nameToSearch, IMappingOptions mappingOptions)
{
    MemberInfo pi = modelProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => NameMatches(prop.Name, nameToSearch));
    if (pi != null)
        return pi;

  ...

    pi = modelProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => NameMatches(mappingOptions.SourceMemberNameTransformer(prop.Name), nameToSearch));
    if (pi != null)
        return pi;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work "out of the box":

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FooConfig, Foo>()
    .ForMember(d => d.BarValues, o => o.MapFrom(s => new Bar { A = s.A, B = s.B }))
    .ForMember(d => d.BarErrorValues, o => o.MapFrom(s => new Bar {A = s.AError, B = s.BError}));
```

Comment: Hi Patrick. I am trying to avoid writing ForMember for every member (I have 50+ in reality). The way I see it if I am going to be doing that then I may as well be writing a manual X = Y function